# Java NoClassDefFoundError Exception for JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I never used JSON so this is the first time. But I cannot even get it to work correctly.

```
import org.json.*; // get everything !

//method not even done yet... 
public static String getJSON( String jsonSource, String key ) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject( jsonSource );
    return null;
}
```

This small piece of code will throw an Exception. Compiling it also gave me warnings.

> warning: json-20141113.jar(org/json/JSONObject.class): major version
>   52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this
>   compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

I'm running linux mint 17 with this version of java :

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Is that the reason why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

JDK 8 = 52 and JDK 7 = 51, the json-*.jar you use has been compiled with JDK 8 and you're compiling your code with JDK 7.

Find another version of json for JDK 7 or compile your code with JDK 8.

By the way, for JSON you should have a look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your JDK. Your dependency uses Java 8, and you try to compile your code with JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using has been compiled for JDK 8.
See https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Fortunately no JDK 8 feature has been used in code. In fact, except for a couple of multi catch statements (JDK 7), code is JDK 5 compatible.

I forked that repository
https://github.com/makeroo/JSON-java
and recompiled code for JDK 5 (my requirement was JDK 6 actually but I choose minimum code requirement).